# How to serve static files in Flask with Blueprints

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I had a Flask app that worked fine until, due to growth, I decided to modularize. The new structure is as follows:

```
├── Dockerfile
├── README.md
├── app
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── config.py
│   ├── cron.py
│   ├── database.ini
│   ├── db.py
│   ├── db.sqlite3
│   └── webapp
│       ├── __init__.py
│       └── routes.py
├── db.sqlite3
├── docker-compose.yml
├── error.log
├── gunicorn_config.py
├── rd.py
├── requirements.txt
├── static
│   ├── css
│   │   └── bootstrap.min.css
│   ├── data.html
│   ├── fonts
│   │   ├── glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot
│   │   ├── glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg
│   │   ├── glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf
│   │   ├── glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff
│   │   └── glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2
│   ├── images
│   │   ├── ajax-loader.gif
│   │   ├── gear.png
│   │   ├── gear_small.png
│   │   └── logo.png
│   ├── index.html
│   ├── js
│   │   ├── app.js
│   │   ├── bootbox.min.js
│   │   ├── bootstrap.js
│   │   ├── bootstrap.min.js
│   │   └── npm.js
│   ├── login.html
│   ├── manage_users.html
│   ├── register.html
│   ├── reset_password.html
│   ├── settings.html
│   └── upload.html
└── templates
    └── base.html
```

Here is the `__init__.py` for webapp:

```
from flask import Flask
from app.config import DebugConfig
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from importlib import import_module
from logging import basicConfig, DEBUG, getLogger, StreamHandler
import os

import uuid

def register_blueprints(app):
    for module_name in (app.config['MODULES']):
        module = import_module('app.{}.routes'.format(module_name))
        app.register_blueprint(module.blueprint)

def configure_logs(app):
    basicConfig(filename='error.log', level=DEBUG)
    logger = getLogger()
    logger.addHandler(StreamHandler())

def create_app():
    file = (__file__)
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.secret_key = str(uuid.uuid4())
    app.config.from_object(DebugConfig)
    register_blueprints(app)
    configure_logs(app)

    return app
```

Here is login page route code:

```
@blueprint.route("/login", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def login():

    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template(url_for('static', filename='login.html')
```

Unfortunately this new structure leads to this error when I attempt to serve the app:

> builtins.FileNotFoundError FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file
>   or directory: '/static/login.html'

I have been messing with this for a while now and just can't figure out how to get the app to work and manage to locate the files. I tried setting the `static_url_path` value when instantiating the flask app but, although that manages to locate the HTML files, I'm unable to load the other static files like CSS and images because I have my paths defined relative to the static folder as below in the HTML:

`<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css?version=24" >` or
`<link rel="icon" href="/static/images/gear.png">`

Please assist, I feel like I'm going to pull my hair out as I've spent too much time on this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ideally, you would use a CDN for bootstrap, otherwise a static url, not a relative one. For the gear png, that needs to be gotten as `url_for('static', 'images/gear.png')`

Comment: Also, there's nothing wrong with putting html files without jinja syntax into your templates directory

Comment: Your first suggestion resulted in this error `<link rel="icon" href="{{ url_for('static','/images/gear.png')}}"> jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'url_for' is undefined`

Comment: I actually prefer option 2 since all my HTML files are already written this way, except I really can't figure out how to get the app to determine where the files are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What your are looking for is the [Flask jinja_loader](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.Flask.jinja_loader).

In your create_app method, you could overwrite the jinja_loader provided by default for Flask, which look into the *template_folder* directory to search for file using render_template method.

```
def create_app():
    file = (__file__)
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.secret_key = str(uuid.uuid4())
    app.config.from_object(DebugConfig)
    register_blueprints(app)
    configure_logs(app)

    # Overwrite Flask jinja_loader, using ChoiceLoader
    template_loader = jinja2.ChoiceLoader([
        app.jinja_loader,
        jinja2.FileSystemLoader('/path/to/static'),
    ])
    app.jinja_loader = template_loader

    return app
```

Jinja2 ChoiceLoader look for template in the list of loaders.
So first in app.jinja_loader : the template_folder directory.
Then using the FileSystemLoader in the /static directory.
Be warn that if you have a template something.html in both the template and the static directory, the first one will be returned.

But Jinja2 has more loader than just the CoiceLoader and you should try to find one that suite your desires. For exemple the [DictLoader](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/api/#jinja2.DictLoader) with a key 'static' could be fine also

Comment: so do I explicitly set `static_folder` or `static_url_path`? Tried adding the amendment you suggested with `static_url_path` set and the template wasn't found. With it neither set or with the `static_folder` set, I'm getting this error: `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/static/login.html'`. This is so confusing and frustrating.

Comment: Neither ! static_folder is used when Flask try to look for static files, which are not rendered with Jinja2. As suggested by cricket_007, try first to follows the documentation and put Jinja2 templates together in the template directory. Or, read documentation about Flask jinja_loader which never talks about static_folder.